# Is it possible to overflow an Oracle NUMBER type?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm working with process scheduling software called Appworx. In it, each process and subprocess can have an arbitrary number of "conditions", which if true, some conditional action is taken.

One of the possible conditional actions is a goto statement, where a plain integer is the label (each condition being numbered starting at 1). I'd like to use this feature to evaluate and run a few tasks in a loop, but you can only *goto* higher-numbered conditions (Don't ask me why... this seems to ruin most of the utility).

I have reason to believe that all of this is evaluated by Oracle on the backend. And having looked at the schema for Appworx, it appears that the *goto* labels are all NUMBER(12,0). I suspect that the logic that checks whether a label is lower than the current condition is something like:

```
where label > current_condition
```

So, if I were to supply a goto with a high enough value, I think it would cheat the checking and allow me to do simple loops. At least if Oracle used normal integers. Is it possible to overflow them, and what value would I use to overflow the value back to 1?

I suppose the Oracle version matters quite a bit, if so, it's 11g.

PS Also, if anyone would care to re-tag this for me, please add "appworx"

Comment: Yes, PL/SQL can overflow an integer declared as `number(12,0)`. Unlike some programming languages, it catches that error and raises an exception instead of rolling over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle numbers are in fact floating point numbers with 40 decimal digit significand.
So, they can't be overflowed.

(10^40-1) is the maximal integer number which can be increased by 1.
[proof](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55c44/9)

NUMBER(12,0) is a subtype of type NUMBER.
That is, it consists of NUMBER type and a restriction checker.

Comment: I think that it's important to note that the Oracle Number data type is a base 10 floating point, not the base 2 IEEE754-type usually encountered in computing systems. I'm not sure that that has an impact on whether they can overflow or not -- that's really a matter of how the software treats overflow situations (representing as infinity, for example, as IEEE754 does).

Answer (score 2):

Well, that depends on your definition of 'overflow'.  If you define 'overflow' as 'find a value **n** where **n** + 1 < **n**', then no, there's no such value.  If you define 'overflow' as 'raises an exception', then yes, it's quite possible to perform an operation on a NUMBER(12,0) where an exception is raised.

Run the following:

```
DECLARE
  n  NUMBER(12, 0);
BEGIN
  n := 999999999999;  -- Twelve 9's
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('1 : n=' || n);
  n := n + 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('2 : n=' || n);
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Exception: ' || SQLCODE || '  ' || SQLERRM);
END;
```

As you can see, the following exception is thrown when attempting to execute "n := n + 1":

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
```

So it's quite possible to overflow a subtype of NUMBER.  However, given that you're hoping to find a value **n** where **n** + 1 < **n**, I think you're out of luck.

And if you really want to provoke this behavior using the base NUMBER type, just execute

```
n := POWER(10, 126);
```

Of course, for truly ***nasty*** behavior in NUMBER you need to get it to produce a NaN (Not a Number):

```
n := 9999999999999999999999999999999999999999 * POWER(10, 125);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('n=' || n);
```

produces

```
n=~
```

WTF?!?  '~'?  What the heck is '~'?  Well, it appears that this is Oracle's way of printing a NaN.  And the really *fun* part?  Once you've got a NaN in a variable, any operation you perform on that variable will produce another NaN.  Quietly.  Silently.  Without warning.  Without recourse.  Try:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('n * 1234=' || n * 1234);  -- produces n * 1234=~
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('n / 5678=' || n / 5678);  -- produces n / 5678=~
```

Hey - have fun sweating your financials!  :-)

In actual practice you're very unlikely to encounter this behavior, but it's the kind of thing you really need to be aware of - not only because encountering it can really ruin your month, but because (and you can count on this) next week the clueless guy in the cube by the bathroom is going to be asking about this - and *you* will now know all about it.  (And you will now be able to rest easy, comfortable in the knowledge that this guy really *is* clueless and thus deserves to be parked in The Cube From Hell.  I mean, you picked up on this on StackOverflow, right?  So how hard can it be? :-)

Share and enjoy.