# in oracle sql, if the range of value inserted in table exceeds the range of data type then why automatically zeros are getting added

Tags: sql, oracle

in oracle sql, I have created a table with field (salary number) with number data type.

I inserted data like this. emp(333333333333333333333333333334444444444444444444444455555555555555);  then the value stored in the table record is 333333333333333333333333333334444444444400000000000000000000000000. as you see all zero's are added after 40 digits, why this happen so.

thanks..

Comment: Why the MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have a look at [ask]; please edit your question adding your statement and table structure, and leaving only right tags.

Comment: To make more readable this question you should provide your table structure too (ie.your emp table)

Comment: See: [Is it possible to overflow an Oracle NUMBER type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15484564/1509264) and [REAL datatype in PLSQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34593963/real-datatype-in-plsql)

Answer (score 0):

According to Oracle's documentation on [number data type](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements001.htm#sthref119):

> p is the precision, or the maximum number of significant decimal digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit. Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to 20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits depending on the position of the decimal point.

By adding more than 40 significant digits you exhausted the available non-zero digits, therefore Oracle replaced the remaining less significant digits (closer to the decimal point) with zeros.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3810):

> **`NUMBER` Datatype**
>
> The NUMBER datatype stores fixed and floating-point numbers. Numbers of virtually any magnitude can be stored and are guaranteed portable among different systems operating Oracle, up to 38 digits of precision.

[and](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#sthref3819):

> **Internal Numeric Format**
>
> Oracle stores numeric data in variable-length format. Each value is stored in scientific notation, with 1 byte used to store the exponent and up to 20 bytes to store the mantissa. The resulting value is limited to 38 digits of precision. Oracle does not store leading and trailing zeros. For example, the number 412 is stored in a format similar to 4.12 x 102, with 1 byte used to store the exponent(2) and 2 bytes used to store the three significant digits of the mantissa(4,1,2). Negative numbers include the sign in their length.

And looking at the [`NUMBER` data type documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm):

> Specify a fixed-point number using the following form:
>
> ```
> NUMBER(p,s)
> ```
>
> where:
>
> - `p` is the precision, or the total number of significant decimal digits, where the most significant digit is the left-most nonzero digit, and the least significant digit is the right-most known digit. Oracle guarantees the portability of numbers with precision of up to 20 base-100 digits, which is equivalent to 39 or 40 decimal digits depending on the position of the decimal point.

This means that Oracle only stores the 39 or 40 (depending on where the decimal point is) most significant digits of a number (however, as you can see from the first quote they only guarantee the 38 most-significant digits). Any digits beyond this limit are not stored and Oracle will assume them to be zero.